# Cauchy Functional Equation Extension

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
>   $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=+\infty$ and $f(e^x)=e^{f(x)}, \forall x\in (0,+\infty)$ (note where the last equality holds, it's **not** all of
>   $\mathbb{R}$)
>
> Prove that:
>
> a) $f(x)=e^{f(\ln x)},\forall x\in (0,+\infty)$
>
> b) $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$
>
> c) $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$
>
> d) $f(x)=x,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Now, I am badly stuck on proving a. I have already proved that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=-f(-x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, but I can prove a only on $(1,+\infty)$ and not on $(0,+\infty)$. Any help with that?

Comment: I suppose you mean $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, not just for all $x$ with a fixed $y$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Fixed that! Thank you!

Comment: How does your proof for $(1,+\infty)$ go?

Comment: @tilper Simply substituting $u=e^x$ on the third relation, we get the wanted but only for: $x>0\Rightarrow u>1$.

Comment: Any help here available?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  See [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation).  Any solution not of the form $f(x) = c x$ has its graph dense in the plane...

Comment: The question remains: how to prove (a), in order to prove the (crucial for Cauchy) (c).

Comment: Either the limit statement or $f(e^x) = e^{f(x)}$ implies the graph is not dense.  Then from $c e^x = e^{cx}$ it's easy to find $c$...

Comment: Actually, I need to follow the thought of the questions from (a) to (d) gradually. So, how to prove (a) without proving (b) or (c) or (d)?